# Why is this list slice treating 0 and 1 as the same in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, slice

I'm a bit confused about slicing a list and the numbering here.

Python tends to start from 0 instead of 1, and it's shown below to work in that way well enough. But if we're starting from 0, and going until 3, why am I not getting `exam` instead of `exa`? After all, 0 - 3 is 4 numbers.

```
>>> test = "example string"
>>> print test[:3]
exa
>>> print test[0:3]
exa
>>> print test[1:3]
xa
```

Comment: In Python the range is half-closed. test[0:3] means [0, 3) 3 is *not* included in the range. You can think of it as, "till the third character" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an intentional way, last element is exclusive.

Why is it so?

Firstly, my understanding it is because `test[0:len(test)]` should print all the list and then `test[0:len(test)-1]` excludes one element. This is prettier and more readable than if the last element would be included.

Secondly, it is because if you have `test[:-1]` it will return all the elements, but the last, which is very intuitive. If it would include the second index, to cut the last element you'd have to do `test[:-2]` which is ugly and makes it harder to read...

Also, length of your resulting list is `end - start`, which is yet another convenient feature about it.

Comment: Another reason: `test == test[:n] + test[n:]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have

```
text[0:3]
```

it will return elements from `0` to `3 - 1`.

```
text[0]
text[1]
text[2]
```

not

```
text[3]
```

**In general**, it will return values from `start` to `end - 1`. For further information, you could read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation).